# translate "load more" button

Tags: plugins

I am using Wordpress Visual Composer's Testimonials and I want to translate the Load More button in another language. I made the change in the js-composer_ro-RO.po file using PoEdit and saved the file into wp-content/languages/plugins and then changed the language of the site into Romanian. However, the button didn't change the language.

Thank you

Comment: Please include the code that is generating the button.

Comment: I think this is the code ...

Comment: <a class="button bordered" onclick="load_testimonials(jQuery(this), 9, 9); return false;" href="#">Load more </a>

Comment: in that case it can not be translated

Answer (score 1):

Your link doesn't embed translation for the "Load more" string. 
You need to make a modification. If the code is embed in a php file : _e('load more', 'your_txt_domain');

If the string to translate is in a js file, you need to use wp_localize_script() function.